# Monstera yellowing with brown spots

Tags: houseplants, monstera

A few stats about my Monstera Deliciosa:

- 4.5 years old
- facing East
- at first was growing in soil, after repotting it is now in plant granules (brand - Seramis)
- watering schedule is not very strict, ~2l of water every 1-2 weeks
- we live in north of Germany

My Monstera was growing great up until a few weeks. I started noticing the outside of the leaves yellowing, and now one leaf has developed a brown spot. What could be the issue?

P.S. Repotting will take place in a few weeks.

[image: Whole plant]

[image: Affected leaf][image: Brown spot from up close]

Comment: the growth is looking great! Have you tried trimming and making smaller plants from this?